# Should I not see the normal flag dialog, instead of the version with less options?

Tags: support, flags

I edited [Who does the verb "argues" and preposition "to" refer to in the following sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45326/who-does-the-verb-argues-and-preposition-to-refer-to-in-the-following-senten) which is a question from October 2011, and I looked at the flag dialog to reply to a comment. The dialog box I see is the following one.

[image: screenshot]

I thought I should see the option, "it doesn't belong here."

Differently, the flag dialog I see in [To pay something (in) cash/cache](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44639/to-pay-something-in-cash-cache) is the one I would expect.

[image: screenshot]

It seems like, in the first case, I was considered the author of the question, when I only edited it.

Is it so? Is this what it is supposed to happen?

Comment: You got the first dialog because at some point you voted to close the question. After a while the vote degrades, and you don't see the all familiar `close(1)` but the vote is still there, which makes the `it doesn't belong here` option redundant. [/guess]

Comment: The "close" link is not hidden after users vote to close; if a user voted to close, and try to see the flagging dialog, the "it doesn't belong here" option should be shown. If then the user click on that option, the closing dialog should be the one that shows the user already voted to close. It seems it is happening what you said, though.

Comment: Oh yes, I meant that after a while you don't see the `(1)` part although you've voted... If you click close on the first question, you'll know if you've already voted. I don't see the "it doesn't belong here" option on the flag dialog when voted to close _as off topic_, even after the vote degrades. (just tried it on Programmers)

Comment: @YannisRizos Close votes degrade after a while, but you can never vote to close that question again, so I guess showing that option doesn't make sense. Also, since you solved the mystery, you might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: @lunboks I'm not sure I solved it, if you can confirm that my guess is true, feel free to post an answer. The match starts in a minute, so it's beer time! be back Monday :)

Comment: The point is that the "close" link doesn't disappear, and you are always able to see the dialog box for voting to close, even when you already voted, in the current turn, or any previous one.

Comment: The user may need to flag for a different reason, other than the close/it doesn't belong here reason.